# Welche Präposition nutzt man, um "das Bild gehört ihr" zu sagen?

Tags: grammar, preposition, possessive

Gibt es eine Präposition, die Zugehörigkeit vermittelt? *"Das Bild von ihr"* bedeutet, dass man sie im Bild sehen kann, oder?

Wie sagt man, dass das Bild ihr gehört?

Ist "von" richtig in folgendem Satz richtig?

> Mein Auto ist rot, aber das Auto von Kai ist blau

*"was von jemandem"* – kann man das sagen, um *"das Auto Kais"* oder *"Kais Auto"* zu meinen?

Answer (score 6):

Der Ausdruck

> das Bild von ihr

hat – wenn er in keinem Kontext steht – mindestens zwei Bedeutungen:

1. ein Bild, auf dem sie dargestellt ist
2. ein Bild, das ihr gehört

Ohne Kontext ist nicht sichergestellt, was mit dem Ausdruck gemeint ist.

Erst im Textumfeld wird klar, was genau gemeint ist. Zum Beispiel

> Das Bild von ihr im Ausweis ist gut gelungen.

und

> Das Bild von ihr ist sehr wertvoll. Sie hat es 1994 ersteigert.

Stilistisch gesehen ist der Genitiv in meinem Empfinden meistens schöner als die besitzanzeigende (possessiv) Präposition *von*:

> *Ihr* Bild, das sie im Wohnzimmer hängen hat, gefällt mir sehr.

In deinem Beispiel

> Mein Auto ist rot, aber das Auto von Kai ist blau.

ist die Präposition *von* absolut richtig. Der Satz klingt auch gut und ist gleichwertig zu

> Mein Auto ist rot, aber Kais Auto ist blau.

Comment: Vielleicht solltest du noch dazufügen, dass der Genitiv, wenn vorangestellt, immer wie ein bestimmter Artikel wirkt. "Die Austellung zeigt Van Goghs Werke". Das klingt als zeigte sie alle. Hier würde man sagen "Werke von van Gogh" und es ist eine Bedeutungsunterscheidung vorhanden. Auch ist von besser in Situationen, wo das Genitiv-s "nicht allein ist"

"Thomas' Eltern sind Bauern." vs "Die Eltern von Thomas sind Bauern."

Das erste ist nicht so gut, da man den Genitiv nicht hört, es sei denn, man spricht komisch :)

Comment: Je nach Kontext kann „das Auto von Kai“ auch bedeuten, dass das Auto von Kai stammt (der es beispielsweise verkauft oder verschenkt hat). Ich bin in dieser Hinsicht vielleicht etwas altmodisch, finde aber „Kais Auto“ in der Regel die schönere Formulierung.

Answer (score 4):

> Mein Auto ist rot, aber das Auto von Kai ist blau.

Das ist der weit verbreitete, und übliche Vonativ, spaßeshalber so genannt, weil der Genitiv besser wäre, auch wenn er selten verwendet wird, und zwar in allen 3 Fällen.

> Mein Auto ist rot, aber Kais Auto ist blau.

Der Genitiv ist in allen 3 Fällen besser:

- Ihr Bild zeigt sie ohne Brille.
- Ihr Bild hat sie nicht signiert.
- Ihr Bild wurde durch einen Wasserschaden arg beschädigt.

Wenn die Umstände nicht nahelegen, um welche Art von Beziehung es sich genau handelt dann muss man es dazusagen. Regelmäßig findet auch keine Unterscheidung zwischen Besitz und Eigentum statt: Peters Auto gehört der Bank, aber ist Ferdinand Porsches Entwurf.